# Where to put settings of GUI/View on MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

On my C# 2.0 (.NET CF) program, I need to create a theme based GUI (with Controls that are non .NET and 3rd party) . I will be doing it in such a way that the user can customize the colors, fonts, toolbar/tabcontrol positions and etc. Then I need to store this into some file/XML then later on retrieve it by just using a simple serialization/deserialization. But my problem is where to put this? shall this go to model, view, or controller?

thanks

Comment: @tereško - There you go again, blindly marking things as asp.net-mvc that clearly aren't... you really need to read the question before doing that.

Comment: I don't understand: did you try to convert a .NET 2.0 application into a ASP.MVC web application?

Comment: vandango - actually I dont remember putting asp.net mvc on the tag. when i rechecked my post earlier, my post was edited. if i remember clearly, i originally put C# and mvc. I think Erik Funkenbusch reverted it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A theme based user preferences information is "data" and does not belong to any of the main MVC folders. **Data is always seperate from these folders.**

If you are sure that you don't want to store it in database or NO-SQL data storage, but want to use a file instead, you can create a **seperate folder in the root folder** for this purpose. Alternatively you can use resx files and .NET ResourceManager class if your preferences will be key-value pairs. (RESX tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx )

Please see below for summaries of what model, view, contoller should contain and why they are not suitable to include theme based user preferences.

- **MODEL:** The model "represents" the data, and does nothing else. Representation is the keyword here. User theme preferences are actual data and does not belong to here.
- **VIEW:** The view displays the model data, and sends user actions (e.g. button clicks) to the controller thus it's not suitable for storing a user preferences data.
- **CONTROLLER:** The controller provides model data to the view, and interprets user actions. Your file clearly is not a controller and
  does not belong to here.

(For a detailed explanation of what MVC concepts are and to see some examples: http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)